# Java applet - MouseMotionListener works in eclipse but not on browser

Tags: java, applet, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm having some problems with my java applet...
MouseMotionListener works in eclipse applet viewer but not on browsers(I tried Chrome and Firefox and IE). In the game, I try to move a object using mouse. 
The MouseMotionListener is in the initComponents method.

```
package tk.miloskostadinovski.game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game extends Applet implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // varibles
    Thread thread;
    boolean running = false;
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean pauseRunning = false;

    int width = 600, height = 700;
    int x = 350, y = 560;
    int fruitSpeed = 2;
    int points = 0;
    int lives = 5;
    int basketWH = 100;
    int fruitWH = 70;

    int aX = getRandNumbX(), aY = getRandNumbY();
    int oX = getRandNumbX(), oY = getRandNumbY();
    int sX = getRandNumbX(), sY = getRandNumbY();
    int bX = getRandNumbX(), bY = getRandNumbY();
    int hX = getRandNumbX(), hY = getRandNumbY();
    int basketX = 350;
    int basketY = 580;

    private Image i;
    private Graphics doubleG;

    Image apple, orange, banana, straw, hamburger, background, basket, heart,
            mellon;

    public void init() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(width, height);
        setLayout(null);

        apple = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/apple.png");
        orange = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/orange.png");
        banana = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/banana.png");
        straw = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/straw.gif");
        hamburger = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/hamburger.png");
        background = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/background.jpg");
        basket = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/basket.png");
        heart = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/heart.png");
        mellon = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "pictures/mellon.png");
    }

    public void start() {

    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        if (thread != null) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void run() {
        pauseButton.setVisible(true);
        while (running) {

            while (pauseRunning) {
                repaint();
            }

            fruitMoving();
            repaint();

            if (aY >= height) {
                aY = getRandNumbY();
                aX = getRandNumbX();
                lives--;
            }
            if (oY >= height) {
                oY = getRandNumbY();
                oX = getRandNumbX();
                lives--;
            }
            if (bY >= height) {
                bY = getRandNumbY();
                bX = getRandNumbX();
                lives--;
            }
            if (sY >= height) {
                sY = getRandNumbY();
                sX = getRandNumbX();
                lives--;
            }
            if (hY >= height) {
                hY = getRandNumbY();
                hX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (hY <= basketY + basketWH && hY >= basketY && hX >= basketX - 40
                    && hX <= basketX + basketWH) {
                lives--;
                hY = getRandNumbY();
                hX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (sY <= basketY + basketWH && sY >= basketY && sX >= basketX - 40
                    && sX <= basketX + basketWH) {
                points++;
                sY = getRandNumbY();
                sX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (bY <= basketY + basketWH && bY >= basketY && bX >= basketX - 40
                    && bX <= basketX + basketWH) {
                points++;
                bY = getRandNumbY();
                bX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (oY <= basketY + basketWH && oY >= basketY && oX >= basketX - 40
                    && oX <= basketX + basketWH) {
                points++;
                oY = getRandNumbY();
                oX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (aY <= basketY + basketWH && aY >= basketY && aX >= basketX - 40
                    && aX <= basketX + basketWH) {
                points++;
                aY = getRandNumbY();
                aX = getRandNumbX();
            }

            if (basketX >= width - basketWH) {
                basketX = width - basketWH;
            }
            if (basketX <= 0) {
                basketX = 0;
            }
            if (lives <= 0) {

                tryAgain.setVisible(true);
                while (true) {
                    if (tryAgain.isVisible() == false) {
                        aY = getRandNumbY();
                        aX = getRandNumbX();
                        oY = getRandNumbY();
                        oX = getRandNumbX();
                        sY = getRandNumbY();
                        sX = getRandNumbX();
                        bY = getRandNumbY();
                        bX = getRandNumbX();
                        hY = getRandNumbY();
                        hX = getRandNumbX();

                        lives = 5;
                        points = 0;

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(apple, aX, aY, this);
        g.drawImage(orange, oX, oY, this);
        g.drawImage(banana, bX, bY, this);
        g.drawImage(straw, sX, sY, this);
        g.drawImage(hamburger, hX, hY, this);
        g.drawImage(basket, basketX, basketY, this);
        g.drawImage(heart, 100, 10, this);
        g.drawImage(mellon, 20, 10, this);
        g.setFont(new Font("Seris", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString(lives + "", 125, 30);
        g.drawString(points + "", 50, 30);
        if (lives <= 0) {
            g.setFont(new Font("Seris", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            g.drawString("Game over", 220, 300);
        }
        if (pauseRunning) {
            g.drawString("Game Paused", 220, 300);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (i == null) {
            i = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            doubleG = i.getGraphics();
        }
        doubleG.setColor(getBackground());
        doubleG.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        doubleG.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(doubleG);

        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        // startGame button, pointsBox, livesBox, pause button, game over, play
        // again, resume game

        setFocusable(true);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseMoved(evt);

            }

        });

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }

        });

        startGame = new Button("Start Game");
        startGame.setFocusable(false);
        startGame.setLocation(230, 300);
        startGame.setSize(130, 40);
        startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startGameActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        tryAgain = new Button("Try Again?");
        tryAgain.setFocusable(false);
        tryAgain.setLocation(230, 350);
        tryAgain.setSize(130, 40);
        tryAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tryAgainActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
        tryAgain.setVisible(false);

        pauseButton = new Button("Pause");
        pauseButton.setFocusable(false);
        pauseButton.setLocation(550, 10);
        pauseButton.setSize(40, 25);
        pauseButton.setVisible(false);
        pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pauseButtonActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        add(startGame);
        add(tryAgain);
        add(pauseButton);
    }

    public void startGameActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        startGame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void tryAgainActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        points = 0;
        lives = 5;
        tryAgain.setVisible(false);

    }

    public void pauseButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (pauseRunning == false) {
            pauseRunning = true;

        } else {
            pauseRunning = false;
        }

    }

    public int getRandNumbX() {
        return random.nextInt(520) + 10;
    }

    public int getRandNumbY() {
        return (random.nextInt(+600) + 100) * -1;
    }

    public void fruitMoving() {
        aY += fruitSpeed;
        oY += fruitSpeed;
        sY += fruitSpeed;
        bY += fruitSpeed;
        hY += fruitSpeed;
    }

    public void formMouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point point = new Point(a.getLocation());
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, evt.getComponent());
        basketX = (int) point.getX() - 50;
        repaint();
    }

    public void formKeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        if (pauseRunning == false) {
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                basketX += 20;
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                basketX -= 20;
        }
    }

    // Component declaration
    Button startGame, tryAgain, pauseButton;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using PointerInfo, you should be using the MouseEvent properties, which has already been translated to the local component context. How do you know method is no been called and values are not just been overridden by the program? Place some debug statements in the code a verify if the method is been called and if the values are been adjusted correctly...

Comment: Don't call super.paintComponents from within your paint method, this could cause serious problems

Comment: the super.paintComponents was a mistake. I was testing something and forgot to delete it. Btw, the method is called. I can move the components in eclipse applet viewer.The values are adjusted correctly. It does not work in browser..

Comment: You need to verify that the method is been called in the browser or not, otherwise you could be chasing the wrong problem. You need to add some debug statements to verify if the method is been called when displayed within the browser

Comment: PointerInfo may fall under the restricted security domain of the applet, as it is asking for information about the cursor from a global context, which could be seen as a security risk